# Is it possible to get Skype to show video side-by-side instead of picture-in-picture?

Tags: video, skype

I want to do some live broadcasting of video calls and I'd like to have the two video boxes from a Skype call be side by side instead of picture in picture. Is this possible on either Mac or PC?